# How do I split a string into different cells using app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am wanting to split a string that is in `A1` into multiple cells on row `2` using google sheets app script. What I am currently using is only putting the first letter into `A2`. Here is what I currently have:

```
function SplitInputtedWord() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue().split(""))
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function splitupintoanotherrow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const s = sh.getRange(1,1,).getValue();
  const a = s.split("");
  sh.getRange(2,1,1,a.length).setValues([a]);
}
```

Comment: Is this a ChatGPT answer? There are several mistakes like `getSheetByuName` and some parsing errors.

Comment: I didn't test it and I wrote it in the editor.